# Halarious - Embedded resource field names not being converted with custom naming strategy

Tags: json, rest, hateoas, json-serialization

I am using the HAL-Specification framework:

https://github.com/surech/halarious

http://confluence.surech.ch/display/HAL/halarious+Home

http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html

It appears that embedded resource field names are not being converted correctly when using a custom naming strategy.  Only 'non-HAL' fields are being converted.

**Question: Is there a way to ensure custom naming conventions are applied to embedded resources and not just regular fields?**

I have the following Gson configuration in a custom MessageBodyWriter...

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setFieldNamingStrategy(new AllLowercaseFieldNamingStrategy());
builder.registerTypeAdapter(HalResource.class, new HalSerializer()); 
builder.setExclusionStrategies(new HalExclusionStrategy());
Gson gson = builder.create();
try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream)) {
    writer.write(gson.toJson(resource, HalResource.class));
}
```

The `AllLowercaseFieldNamingStrategy` implementation simply converts the field name to lowercase like so `@Override public String translateName(Field f) { return f.getName().toLowerCase(); }`

For example:

```
public class MyResource implements HalResource {
   private final String myField;
   private final MyResource myEmbeddedResource;
   ...
}
```

results in inconsistent field names (should be all lower case based on naming strategy)...

```
{
    "myfield": "...",
    "_embedded": {
        "myEmbeddedResource": {...}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround solution was to use the `@HalEmbedded` annotation and assign a lowercase name directly.

```
public class MyResource implements HalResource {
   private final String myField;
   @HalEmbedded(name = "myembeddedresource")
   private final MyResource myEmbeddedResource;
   ...
}
```

An issue has been created for the project: https://github.com/surech/halarious/issues/21